# Why doesn't spark.sql.shuffle.partitions work in this case?

Tags: apache-spark

I have this code, before which I set `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "5")`:

```scala
val staticDataFrame = spark.read.format("csv")
   .option("header", "true")
   .option("inferSchema", "true")
   .load("/Users/pavelorekhov/Desktop/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide-master/data/retail-data/by-day/*.csv")
   .cache()

val grouped = staticDataFrame
  .selectExpr(
    "CustomerID",
    "(UnitPrice * Quantity) as total_cost",
    "InvoiceDate"
  )
  .groupBy(col("CustomerID"))
  .sum("total_cost")
  //.cache()
```

when I do `grouped.rdd.getNumPartitions()` I get `1`. But if after `.sum("total_cost")` in `grouped` I uncomment `.cache()`, the number of partitions I get from `grouped.rdd.getNumPartitions()` is `5`.

How does this work exactly? Why isn't the number of partitions `5` without `cache()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of AQE (Adaptive query execution). There's something called "Coalescing of Post Shuffle Partitions", read more about it here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#coalescing-post-shuffle-partitions

Spark coalesces partitions that it deems too small, according to `spark.sql.adaptive.advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes`.

If we disable AQE: `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", "false")` then everything works correctly.

However why `.cache()` makes the number of partitions 5, I don't understand yet.